# How does stack exchange/stack overflow create the pop-up banner at the top of the page...?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, ajax

... the one that you get when you earn a badge or are new to a site?

It's only a little touch, but it looks great and it's my favourite part of the UI.

I want to know how to program that style of pop-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow), of all places.